# FileNotFoundError and shutil.Error when moving specific directories to a new location while maintaining directory structure

Tags: python, shutil, python-os

I have the the following directory structures:

```
/home/usr/source
    fg-2022-07-07
        upload
            CP_results_001
                file.txt
            CP_results_002
                file.txt
            CP_data_001
                file.txt
            CP_data_002
                file.txt

/home/usr/destination
```

I want to move directories containing the string "results_", and their contents, to a new directory (/home/usr/destination) such that the desired final result is as follows:

```
/home/usr/source
    fg-2022-07-07
        upload
            CP_data_001
                file.txt
            CP_data_002
                file.txt

/home/usr/destination
    fg-2022-07-07
        upload
            CP_results_001
                file.txt
            CP_results_002
                file.txt
```

Here's my code:

```
import os
import shutil
 
SRC = '/home/usr/source'
 
DEST = '/home/usr/destination'
  
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(SRC):
    for folders in dirnames:
        if "results_" in folders:
            print('Directory:', folders, 'will be moved from', dirpath, 'to', DEST)
            source_path = os.path.join(dirpath, folders)
            print(source_path)
            destination_path = source_path.replace(SRC, DEST, 1)
            print(destination_path)
            shutil.move(source_path, destination_path)
```

The actual result is as follows:

```
/home/usr/source
    fg-2022-07-07
        upload
            CP_results_001
                file.txt
            CP_results_002
                file.txt
            CP_data_001
                file.txt
            CP_data_002
                file.txt

/home/usr/destination
    fg-2022-07-07
        upload
            CP_results_002
                file.txt
```

I get the following error types (excluding specifics):

```
os.rename(src, real_dst) 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

shutil.Error:
[Errno 22] Invalid argument:
```

So I am getting a partial copy instead of a full move.

Comment: Full error readout 1/3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 563, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/usr/source/fg-2022-07-07/upload/CP_results_002' -> '/home/usr/destination/fg-2022-07-07/upload/CP_results_002'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: Full error readout 2/3: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try10.py", line 18, in <module>
    shutil.move(source_path, destination_path)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 574, in move
    symlinks=True)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 365, in copytree
    raise Error(errors)
shutil.Error: [('/home/usr/source/fg-2022-07-07/upload/CP_results_002/file.txt', '/home/usr/destination/fg-2022-07-07/upload/CP_results_002/file.txt',

Comment: Full error readout 3/3: "[Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/home/usr/destination/fg-2022-07-07/upload/CP_results_002/file.txt'"), ('/home/usr/source/fg-2022-07-07/upload/CP_results_002', '/home/usr/destination/fg-2022-07-07/upload/CP_results_002', "[Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/home/usr/destination/fg-2022-07-07/upload/CP_results_002'")]
srun: error: task 0: Exited with exit code 1